# FastReport 4 and VCL Styles bugs

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, fastreport, vcl-styles

Some background info. I work at a very small company who has recently upgraded Delphi from version 6 (!!!) to Rad Studio XE5 and things have certainly changed a lot in 10+ years. Most things seems to have been improved in the IDE and framework, but we're having big problems with the new VCL Styles feature. It's just very buggy and not up to par with the quality we were used to from Borland back in the day. We have done lots of tweaks and work arounds to get things working but one issue is really bugging me at the moment and it has to do with the preview form in FastReport 4.

1. The toolbar gets a white border around it.
2. Controls in the print dialog and others are misaligned or wrongly positioned

We really want to use VCL Styles to give our software a new fresh look, so we hope there is a solution to these problems.

Steps to reproduce the issues:

1. Create a new VCL Forms Application
2. Check a VCL Style in Project > Options > Application > Appearance, e.g. Sapphire Kamri.
3. Add a TfrxReport report Component to the form
4. Double click the component frxReport1 and add a Page Header band just to have some content
5. Add a TButton and in OnClick event, call frxReport1.ShowReport();
6. Run the program and click on the button. In the preview form you now see that the toolbar is surrounded by a white border which looks weird.
7. Click the leftmost print button to bring up the print dialog and you can see how the group boxes and cancel button is positioned outside of the client area.

Do you have any solutions or suggestions to solve the issues?

[image]

Edit: RRUZ gave a good answer, but there were some side effects to his solution to problem #1 so I decided to simplify the code and just paint the border around the toolbar manually. Like this:

```
procedure TToolBarStyleHookEx.PaintNC(Canvas: TCanvas);
begin
  if TToolBar(Control).BorderWidth>0 then
  begin
    Canvas.Pen.Width := 4;
    Canvas.Pen.Color := StyleServices.GetStyleColor(scWindow);
    Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    Canvas.Rectangle(2,2,Control.Width-2,Control.Height-1);
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Please only one question per question.

Comment: FR has a tool to recompile and change the language. Have a look at the StartMenu ...

Comment: Ok, I have uploaded to http://imgur.com/PlEcLD7. Is it ok to delete only question 3, because 1 and 2 are closely related?

Comment: I have answered this FR question with my comment, so you can remove that ;o)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that recompile thing. I have seen it, but had no idea what it really did. Just the word "recompile" scared me to investigate further, but I'll take alook now.

Comment: Just change the language and recompile ... :o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Effectively both issues it seems VCL Styles bugs.

1) Q: The toolbar gets a white border around it.

A: The `TToolBarStyleHook` Style hook in not handling the BorderWidth property. so you must create a new style hook and override the `PaintNC` to overcome this issue.

```
type
  TToolBarStyleHookEx = class(TToolBarStyleHook)
  protected
    procedure PaintNC(Canvas: TCanvas); override;
  end;

{ TToolBarStyleHookEx }
procedure TToolBarStyleHookEx.PaintNC(Canvas: TCanvas);
var
  Details: TThemedElementDetails;
  LStyle: TCustomStyleServices;
  R: TRect;
begin
  if TToolBar(Control).BorderWidth>0 then
  begin
    LStyle := StyleServices;
    R := Rect(0, 0, Control.Width, Control.Height);
    Details.Element := teToolBar;
    Details.Part := 0;
    Details.State := 0;
    if LStyle.HasTransparentParts(Details) then
      LStyle.DrawParentBackground(Handle, Canvas.Handle, Details, False);
    LStyle.DrawElement(Canvas.Handle, Details, R);
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

and register like so

```
initialization
  TCustomStyleEngine.RegisterStyleHook(TToolBar, TToolBarStyleHookEx);
```

2) Q : Controls in the print dialog and others are misaligned or wrongly positioned

A: It seems a  issue related with the `TFormStyleHook`, you had 3 alternatives.

1) you can edit the *frxPrintDialog* unit and increase the width of the form.

2) you can patch the form style hook.

3) You can change the width of the print dialog in run-time.

Check this code which changes the width of the dialog in run-time using a `HCBT_ACTIVATE` hook

```
var

 hhk: HHOOK;

function CBT_FUNC(nCode: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
const
  ClassNameBufferSize = 1024;
var
 hWindow: HWND;
 RetVal : Integer;
 ClassNameBuffer: Array[0..ClassNameBufferSize-1] of Char;
 i : integer;
begin
   Result := CallNextHookEx(hhk, nCode, wParam, lParam);
   if nCode<0 then exit;
   case nCode of
     HCBT_ACTIVATE:
     begin
       hWindow := HWND(wParam);
       if (hWindow>0) then
       begin
          RetVal := GetClassName(wParam, ClassNameBuffer, SizeOf(ClassNameBuffer));
          if (RetVal>0) and SameText(ClassNameBuffer, 'TfrxPrintDialog') then
          for i:= 0 to Screen.FormCount-1 do
          if (SameText(Screen.Forms[i].ClassName, 'TfrxPrintDialog')) and (Screen.Forms[i].Width<=563) then
            Screen.Forms[i].Width:=Screen.Forms[i].Width+8;
       end;
     end;
   end;

end;

Procedure InitHook();
var
  dwThreadID : DWORD;
begin
  dwThreadID := GetCurrentThreadId;
  hhk := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, @CBT_FUNC, hInstance, dwThreadID);
  if hhk=0 then RaiseLastOSError;
end;

Procedure KillHook();
begin
  if (hhk <> 0) then
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk);
end;

initialization
  InitHook();

finalization
  KillHook();
```

After of apply both fixes this will be the result

[image]

[image]

Note: please report these issues to the [QC page of Embarcadero](http://qc.embarcadero.com/).

Comment: Thank you so much! I honestly didn't think there would be an answer to this! Your solution works really well for question #2, and also for question #1, but when I move the mouse over the toolbar it flickers and sometimes the "zoom" combobox and page number editbox disappears. Did you get this symptom aswell?

Comment: I must be blind. I can see in your screenshot now that the combobox and edit are not visible :)

Comment: Regarding the side effects of the toolbar style hook, I decided to simplify things and just paint the borders around the toolbar manually. I have edited my post with this solution.

Comment: The issue it seems related to the controls (TEdit, TSpin) painted over the toolbar. without these controls the style hook posted on the answer works fine. I don't have much time to dig more on this right now, but I see which you found an alternative workaround. As advice try using the borderwith property instead of use fixed values.

Comment: Yes, it would work without the special controls, but it would still flicker. The toolbar does not flicker if the stylehook isn't active, at least on my computer. But your answer led me to a good enough solution so thank you for that :) I went with borderwidth at first, but it's actually 2 instead of 4 so there would be some white area left if I used it. Also im just adressing this specific toolbar in our application so it's fine to use fixed value in this case.